# RegEx Address Parsing City

Tags: regex

In our database we have 1 "Address" field that stores the complete address as text.  I am in the process of splitting the address into the following fields:  Line1, City, State, Zip.  (US Addresses).  I have good expressions for parsing the state and zip, but I'm having a bit of difficulty parsing the city.

Basically, I am using the following rules for parsing the city:

- It must come right before the state
- It can have a comma, or two or more spaces before it.
- If neither of the above are true, then just return the 1 word that comes before the state.

I am not interested in validating these addresses.

Here's an example of the RegEx that I've been working with, and it works great for parsing address components that are separated by a comma or more than 2 spaces, but I can't get it work if I try to include an alternative of the 1 proceeding word:

Sample Address:  1977 S. Joshua Tree PL, Palm Springs, CA 92264

.*(?i)(?((((,\s|\s{2,})\w+)+(\s\w+)))(?=(,\s+|\s+)(Alabama|Alaska|Arizona|Arkansas|California|Colorado|Connecticut|Delaware|Florida|Georgia|Hawaii|Idaho|Illinois|Indiana|Iowa|Kansas|Kentucky|Louisiana|Maine|Maryland|Massachusetts|Michigan|Minnesota|Mississippi|Missouri|Montana|Nebraska|Nevada|New Hampshire|New Jersey|New Mexico|New York|North Carolina|North Dakota|Ohio|Oklahoma|Oregon|Pennsylvania|Rhode Island|South Carolina|South Dakota|Tennessee|Texas|Utah|Vermont|Virginia|Washington|West Virginia|Wisconsin|AL|AK|AZ|AR|CA|CO|CT|DE|FL|GA|HI|ID|IL|IN|IA|KS|KY|LA|ME|MD|MA|MI|MN|MS|MO|MT|NE|NV|NH|NJ|NM|NY|NC|ND|OH|OK|OR|PA|RI|SC|SD|TN|TX|UT|VT|VA|WA|WV|WI|WY)))

Trying to make the 1st word optional causes the expression to only return "Springs", instead of "Palm Springs", which definitely matches in the expression above:
.*(?i)(?((((,\s|\s{2,})\w+)**?**(\s\w+)))(?=(,\s+|\s+)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Which regex implementation are you using?

Comment: You're not technically validating addresses here (as to all your states etc.), as one could simply type `666 Devils Street, Devil County, HI 66666`, so a broader address may be fine.

Comment: willOEM:  Using .NET.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think I would take a totally different approach.  I would treat the zip code as authoritative, as it is the most granular data you have available. I would get a list of zip code to city mappings.  Extract the zip code portion of the address.  Write in new database fields the city and state values based on the zip code.  Then write a script to go through each data entry and determine if the city and state names based on zip code can be found in your string.  If they can, remove those values from the string. And flag that record as successfully processed.  If they can't flag the record as one that you might need to perform manual review on.

Another alternate approach might be to use an API like Google Maps, to send your address string to and hopefully get a cleaned address out.

Comment: Google API works great, however it is not an option, since it has a daily limit that is lower than what I need; plus it is $10k for a 1 year company license to cover unlimited requests.

I probably won't opt for the zipcode db since I'm using a RegEx library in sql server.  Thx Tho!

Comment: @user2540060 Just because you have a regex library available to you, doesn't mean it is the best tool for the job. You still have not solved the problem of how regex is going to help with you inconsistently formatted address data.  Even as a human reading the data, you might not be able to tell where the street ends and the city begins without having reference to an authoritative list of city names. You say you want to avoid validation, but I don't see how you can avoid some sort of validation if you want to get the data as accurate as possible with minimal manual human review.

Answer (score 1):

This may be overly broad, but it might work for you, depending on the regex implementation you are using:

```
(.+?),\s*(.+?)(?:,\s|\s\s)(.+?)\s(\d{5})
```

This will return the following groups from your example:

```
('1977 S. Joshua Tree PL', 'Palm Springs', 'CA', '92264')
```

Comment: This is closer to what I'm looking for.  The only thing is, what if an address doesn't have any delimiters?  For example:

1977 S. Joshua Tree PL Palm Springs CA 92264  (should parse "Springs" only)

Comment: If the address does not contain any delimiters between the street and city, it will be impossible to accurately split the two, unless you also add extra validation, such as a list of acceptable cities or street abbreviations.

Comment: Yes, I understand the complexity to it.  However, if we compare it against a list of acceptable cities, then we start to get into validation, which I don't want to do.  If a person enters Xx Xx Ca 92264., then as far as I'm concerned it's a valid address.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Btw, what does it do when you group the delimiters via "?:"?  Eg:  (?:,\s|\s\s)

Comment: Grouping using (?:...) will prevent the enclosed characters from being returned as a match group.  This does not work for all regex implementations.

Answer (score -1):

I always prefer named capture groups for something like this. So try

```
(?<addr>[^,]+),\s+(?<city>[^,]+),\s+(?<state>[A-Za-z]{2})\s+(?<zip>\d{5}(-\d{4})?)
```

Parsing your example this will give you

- addr: 1997 S. Joshua Tree PL
- city: Palm Springs
- state: CA
- zip: 92264

and I threw in support for the extended postal code format as well.

You can just extract the value of the city group from the match generated by this regex.

Comment: Thank you for your response!  This would work great if all of the addresses were comma delimited.  However, there are a lot of addresses that do not have any delimiters at all, for example:

1977 S. Joshua Tree PL Palm Springs CA 92264

Comment: You're not likely to catch everything with one pass. Your best bet would be to run queries, validate the input, update the data, then run more queries on the remaining set until you get to the point where you can manually fix the remaining issues.

Comment: stack247 - you're right, the zip match as coded only worked for a 5+4 formated zipcode. I've corrected it to work for either a 5 or a 5+4.